# Use Weka trained model to predict simultaneously while straming text from a Text Streaming API in Java

Tags: java, weka

I have trained a model using Weka and I am able to derive its predictions for any given text file using my java code.

However, I am not able to do the same for each line given a text streaming API in an efficient manner.

```
For( Each Sentence )
    Predicted_Class = WekaModel.predict(Sentence)
```

The only way I am able to accomplish this is by converting each line to an arff file, predicting the output and then storing it. Though this approach uses too much of I/O.

Can anyone suggest me a better mechanism?